# Infopath Dropdown filtering based on lookup column values?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, infopath2010

I have a problem with filtering a dropdown in Infopath. I have two lists in Sharepoint. In List A there is a column which lists Company names, in list B there is a column that lists Employees. The Company names from List A are used as a lookup in List B, so that each employee has an assigned company.

The problem arises when I need to implement filtering logic in Infopath. In infopath I have two dropdown lists that connect to each list and display all the values in those columns. I need to filter the employee based on the company selected in the first dropdown. However since the values on list B are lookup values I cannot do a straight comparsion of the two values.i have tried to filter on a couple of different fields but I can't figure out this logic. Is there a way to filter based on lookup values?

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure you are filtering your Employee dropdown by the Company field.

Here is what I did to get things working.

**Created two lists:**
  Company
     field: Title

Employee
    field: Title
    field: lookup to Company:Title
           -field name: CompanyLookup

**InfoPath Data Connections**
CompanyDS:
  fields selected ID and Title
EmployeeDS:
  fields selected Title, CompanyLookup, ID

**InfoPath fields**
Dropdown titled Company

- Datasource: CompanyDS
- Value: ID
- Display name: Title

Dropdown titled Employee

- Datasource: EmployeeDS
- Value: Title
- Display name: Title
- Click the tree-view button on the Entries property

  - select the first folder under dataFields. Mine is title d:SharePointListItem_RW

    - Click the Filter Data... button
    - Click Add...
    - First dropdown select CompanyLookup, second dropdown: is equal to
    - Third dropdown pick Select a field or group. Change the Fields dropdown to Main, then select Company.

I'd post pics, but I'm lacking enough **"rep"** points.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but how? CompanyLookup is Company Name (text), and the Company which has Value:ID (number?). Just trying to understand this.